# ant copy from absolute path read from xml

Tags: ant

My problem is, I have to read the source path for a copy job from an xml file and then copy all files in that dir read from the xml file to another dir.

Since code is more than words:

```
<xmltask source="${projectfile}">
  <copy path="Project/RecentResultsInfo/ResultsDirectoryOfRecentLoadTest/text()" property="recentdir" attrValue="true"/>
</xmltask>
<copy todir="${targetdirectory}">
  <fileset dir="${recentdir}"/>
</copy>
```

The output when running this target is:
C:\develop\build.xml:44: Warning: Could not find resource file "C:\develop\C:\Programme\tool\test_90\" to copy.

It seems in fileset it does not recognize, that `recentdir` holds a full path inside. The written xml from the application has a newline before and after the path in the xml file that is read with the path. So ant does not recognize the path since theres a newline in front of it.

Is there anything like trim for ant?

Can anybody help me getting ant to accept that path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Done it now by using Ant-Contrib, but that is used in this project anyway.

```
<xmltask source="${projectfile}">
  <copy path="Project/RecentResultsInfo/ResultsDirectoryOfRecentLoadTest/text()" property="recentdirraw" attrValue="true"/>
</xmltask>
<!-- replace newlines and whitespace from read path -->
<propertyregex property="recentdir" input="${recentdirraw}" regexp="^[ \t\n]+|[ \t\n]+$" replace="" casesensitive="false" />
<copy todir="${targetdirectory}">
  <fileset dir="${recentdir}"/>
</copy>
```

Simply modifying the property with a regex trimming the text by striping of whitespace and newlines.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see, the copy element in [xmltask](http://www.oopsconsultancy.com/software/xmltask/) provides a trim attribute.

```
trims leading/trailing spaces when writing to properties
```

Does that work?